# Ресайз textarea при получении данных с сервера через ajax

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, textarea

У меня есть два окна, в одно пишутся данные с пхп скрипта с помощью ajax в виде строки. Во второе пользователь вводит данные. Я реализовал с помощью jquery расширения http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize анимированный корректно работающий авторесайз textarea. Все работает четко если вводить данные вручную между тэгами:
`<textarea>ВВОДИМ СЮДА</textarea>`. Но если данные поля обновляет ajax, то никакого ресайза не происходит.
Версия jquery - 1.8.1, версия либы autosize.js - v1.18.1.
Фрагменты коды странички

```
<script>
function show()  
{  
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST",   
        url: "myscipt.php",  
        cache: false, 
        data: 'mydata=data&mykey=<?php echo $_SESSION['mykey']; ?>',
        success: function (response) {
            $("textarea#read").val(response);
        } 
    });  
}
$(document).ready(function(){  
show();  
setInterval('show()',3000);  
});  
$(function(){
$('.normal').autosize();
$('.animated').autosize({append: "\n"});
});
</script>
```

Само поле, которое нужно ресайзить:
    `<textarea cols rows readonly id="read"  class='form-control textareasyncget animated' placeholder='mytext' type='text' name='readdata'></textarea><br>`

И второе поле, которое ресайзится без проблем при вводе текста вручную пользователем:
    `<textarea class="form-control form_textarea animated" name="dataforwrite" placeholder="mytext2" id="dataforwrite" pattern=".{5,65535}" required title="5 to 65535 characters"></textarea>`

Собственно и первое ресайзится, если убрать `readonly` и писать туда текст вручную. Нужно сделать так, чтобы при ajax запросе поле само расширялось по вертикали, с анимацией.
Я пробовал генерировать через `echo` в пхп скрипте все поле `textarea` с введенным значением(из переменной скрипта) и выводить его через ajax как html код. Но оно также не ресайзится. Подскажите пожалуйста, буду признателен. Да, в javascript я ноль. Никогда с ним не работал, но задачку нужно решить.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел временное решение без красивой анимации. Создаем стиль:

```
.mytextarea {
padding : 20px 10px 10px 35px;background : #DEDEDE;
border-top : 2px solid #cccccc;
border-right : 2px solid #cccccc;
border-bottom : 2px solid #cccccc;
border-left : 2px solid #cccccc;
border-radius: 5px; размер рамки
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Дальше все как и было выше, только вместо `<textarea>` выводим `<div class='mytextarea' id='read'></div>` и получаем формочку, похожую на задуманную.
Это подойдет как временное решение, пока не решится вопрос с анимированным блоков `<textarea>` в вопросе.